# Bigquery udf supported outside the Bigquery API

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using a third party tool to query our data stored in Bigquery.  The third party tool uses a Bigquery JDBC driver. I would like to take advantage of UDF's  but I do not see any documentation or support for UDF's and the jdbc driver.  Is it supported?  If not is there an ETA?

Comment: what problem do you want to solve with UDFs?

Comment: I'd assume right now it's not supported, as it's only supported in the API. I don't think you'll be able to get an ETA on it, short of making a feature request for it here https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list (and even then, you might not get an ETA).

Comment: @Pentium10 I want to parse a plist that is stored in a field on the fly without having to ETL it.  I'm ETL'ing it now and being able to write little UDF's to do things like this would be very handy.  Unfortunately it looks like its only available via the API

Answer (score 0):

we're currently only supporting UDFs through the API, but do have work planned to support declarative definition (and persistence) of your functions.  This won't be shipped before 2016.

Just out of curiosity, what tool are you using?  Tableau?

Answer (score 0):

There is an inline way to define a UDF, but it is "alpha", unsupported, and undocumented. Use at your own risk.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36208489/2259571